# Designing a Chrome theme, what's going wrong?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-theme

(So, I'm a graphic designer/artist and I'm new to any type of code or script.)

In my Chrome Theme code, I get an error:

> *"Could not load extension from 'E:\Web\dev\theme\dev\Test'. Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 7, column: 4, Syntax error."*

I do not know where I'm going wrong as the specified syntax error is at a blank space, as shown in this code sample:

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "version": 2.0
      "name": "Test",
        "theme": {
          "images" : {
          "theme_frame" : "images/frame.png",
          "theme_toolbar" : "images/toolbar.png",
          "theme_ntp_background" : "images/polygons.png",
          "theme_tab_background" : "images/tab.png",
          "theme_ntp_attribution" : "images/theme_ntp_attribution.png"
        },
        "colors" : {
            "ntp_link": [255,255,255],
        "ntp_text": [255,255,255],
        "ntp_section_link": [255,255,255],
        "ntp_section_text": [10 , 17 , 27],
        "ntp_background": [10 , 17 , 27],
        "frame": [10 , 17 , 27],
        "toolbar": [10 , 17 , 27],
        "tab_text": [255,255,255],
        "tab_background_text": [10 , 17 , 27],
        "bookmark_text": [255,255,255]
        },
        "tints" : {
                    "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom",
        "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
        }
      }
    }
```

So, Where *am* going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put comma on line

```
"version": 2.0
```

By the way, you can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON.

Comment: @peter So, I added the comma, but the error message now says:
> Could not load extension from 'E:\Web\dev\theme\dev\Test'. Required value 'version is missing or invalid. It must be between 1-4 dot-separated integers each between 0 and 65536
(This is the current state):
`{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": 2.0,
  "name": "Test", etc`

Comment: Try to wrap 2.0 in quotes.